# LabView: fixed size array

Tags: arrays, labview

is there a way to create a *fixed size* array in LabView?

I know that I can do some check on the array size, then discard values when an array size become greater than a specific value. But, I think that is a common problem, so there is some built in function in LabView to have a fixed size array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know this is impossible, unless they changed something in one of their latest releases but I doubt it: it would probably require a serious rewrite of the core array code.

The closest you can get is writing your own (possibly polymorphic) array class in which you encapsulate an actual array, that you initialize once with a certain size. For the rest your class only exposes methods to get/set by index. No resize etc.

Or, if you are talking about arrays of controls etc on the front panel, you can probably do this at the UI level by hide the indexing control from it and making sure it cannot be resized graphically. Or probably it's also doable to create a custom control and strip lots of array functionality from it.

Answer (score 2):

If the array size is fixed at design time, then you might consider using a cluster instead. There is even a primitive to convert an array to a cluster of fixed size, provided the length is less then 257. (Array To Cluster function.)

There is also a primitive to go the other way if you need to index the array.

Answer (score 1):

One implementation that you could do is a queue with a fixed size. You can use preview queue and flush queue to implement the functionality you want. However a specific custom class is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

In regular desktop LabVIEW, fixed-sized arrays would be something you'd have to code as per the answers you've already gotten here. However, in LabVIEW FPGA with, say, cRIO, all arrays must be fixed-size.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the *Call Library Function Node* to a WINAPI DLL, there are times where a structure element may be officially be defined as BYTE[130].  So how do you **absolutely, positively** make sure your cluster has exactly the space for 130 bytes?

You can't do it with arrays no matter what, because LabVIEW arrays are pointers to a structure (*the first element being the length*), meaning any array you insert will only allocate enough space for a pointer, 4 bytes.

The work-around I came up with is to insert a cluster that includes sixteen U64 and one U16, pass that through an *unflatten to string* and you'll find it's exactly 130 bytes long.

When the cluster returns from the call, merely *type cast* the *flattened into string* results into a U8 array

Comment: Wow, this is like a time travelling machine! Almost 9 years after, I do not even remember why I needed fixed size arrays, but I see it's still impossible. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I'm not sure, seems I can create a user-defined type, I saw somewhere that user-defined variants are a thang.  But I'm not that motivated to look it up, especially when I have a workaround.